# Listing max value within a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running an SQL query on a MySQL database that lists rows that fall between a certain time. For each date the query returns a number of values. I want the query to return the highest value for each date.

```
SELECT * FROM Syslog.SystemEvents
WHERE Message LIKE '%9c:2e:a1:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: disassociated'
AND TIME(ReceivedAt) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '09:00:00'
ORDER BY ReceivedAt DESC;
```

This query returns something like this:

```
2019-09-17 08:07:14
2019-09-17 08:04:59
2019-09-17 08:04:45
2019-09-17 08:04:05
2019-09-17 08:01:48
2019-09-17 08:01:32
2019-09-17 07:06:44
2019-09-17 07:01:31
2019-09-16 08:06:14
2019-09-16 07:55:28
2019-09-16 07:55:25
2019-09-16 07:54:31
```

What I would like to see is something like this

```
2019-09-17 08:07:14
2019-09-16 08:06:14
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try below - using `max()` and `group by`

```
SELECT max(ReceivedAt) FROM Syslog.SystemEvents
WHERE Message LIKE '%9c:2e:a1:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: disassociated'
AND TIME(ReceivedAt) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '09:00:00'
group by date(ReceivedAt)
ORDER BY ReceivedAt DESC;
```

Comment: Thankyou for that response. The eventual query looked like this:  SELECT DATE(ReceivedAt), max(TIME(ReceivedAt)) AS maxtime FROM Syslog.SystemEvents
WHERE Message LIKE '%9c:2e:a1:xx:xx:xx IEEE 802.11: disassociated'
AND TIME(ReceivedAt) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '09:00:00'
group by DATE(ReceivedAt)
ORDER BY DATE(ReceivedAt) DESC;